# How to optimize large pandas dataframe which is using groupby and aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I am reading an excel file with about 300k rows  to a pandas dataframe. I am, 
then, grouping it to about 18000 rows using groupby. Then, I am looping each group and calculating sum doing a filter (date filter for month data) in the group. The whole process is taking about 60 minutes. Is there any way to optimize this? The code is as follows:

```
    qgift_dl = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='latin1')
    qgift_dl['user_id'] = df1['user_id'].astype(str)  # read csv file
    qgift_dl['Gift Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Gift Date'])
    min_date = qgift_dl['Gift Date'].min()
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    qgift_dates = get_date_range(min_date, today) # get all dates between
    q_grouped = qgift_dl.groupby(['user_id'])
    details= []
    for group in q_grouped:
        d_rows = group[1]
        d_row_data = [group[0]]  # add donor id
        for dt in qgift_dates:
            lower = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')
            upper = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            filtered = d_rows[(d_rows['Gift Date'] >= lower) & (d_rows['Gift Date'] <= upper)]
            d_row_data.append(filtered['Amount'].sum())
        details.append(d_row_data)
```

Below is get_date_range function. It gets range of all date (Y-m-d) between two ranges. In my case the range is '2008-04-30' to '2020-05-30'.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime, calendar

def get_date_range(start, end):

    result = []
    while start <= end:
        result.append(start)
        start += relativedelta(months=1)
    return result
```

Sample Excel data is as follow:
[image: sample excel data]
Link to sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeH35w0rqVoHukGTSDtISlztdZAiDYsmfLWVia2x1U0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? And what is `get_date_range`? How can we try to reproduce?

Comment: I have updated the question with sample data and get_date_range def. The original data is around 300k. Thanks

Comment: I still cannot copy-paste from a png file... You say you get all dates, but `get_date_range` adds (more or less...) month. Without some copyable data and the expected result, I cannot help you.

Comment: Hi I updated the question to explain how exactly the dataframe is created and also included link to a sample file. The columns that matter are user_id, Gift Date and Amount.

Comment: @user3929745 do you mind to explain what lower and upper are supposed to be here?
It will be great if you can add what is the expected output  too.

Comment: It looks to me that you are looking for the cumulative sum of amount donation from the beginning of the month to date within any element of the group. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, I am looking for total amount for all months between 2008 to 2020 for each user. see the link here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Q23MxhDTqMdDgosPq6LfT-bkMDtx5TmK3d9StJQ90I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the expected result, you want the total amount per user and per month. The pandas tools are `groupby` and `sum`, and `unstack` if you want the dates to be the columns:

```
result = df.groupby(['user_id', pd.to_datetime(df['Gift Date'], dayfirst=True
                    )+ pd.offsets.Day() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()])[['Amount']].sum(
             ).unstack()
```